# Check SQLite table entry field - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm wanting to check a boolean field of a table entry called isSolved. Then write an if condition which runs code dependant on the boolean value.

I have tried this approach:

```
    foreach (int level in builtInLevels2)
    {
        myImage = new Image();
        int levelNowInt = level;
        string levelName = "Level " + level;
        SQLiteConnection sqlConnection;
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
        try
        {
            // create a new database connection:
            sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);

            // open the connection:
            sqlConnection.Open();

            // create a new SQL command:

            sqlite_cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "select isSolved from Level where name = " + "'" + levelName + "'" + ";";
            var dbEntry = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(dbEntry.ToString());
        }
```

var dbEntry is always 0. However this is not a boolean value, as the boolean value for the table entry is actually 1 in some cases.  How do i do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
var isSolved = (bool)sqlite_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

From the documentation for [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value from a database.

From the documentation for [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> For all other types of statements (other than UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE), the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Given the documentation, I'd expect you'd get back a `-1`, not `0`.